# mixing SQLite DB and GetSharedPreferences()

Tags: android, sqlite

I have question and hope won't take you a lot of time. I'm doing calorie counter application I'll store the foods, exercises in SQLite DB. However I'm not sure do I need to use DB  to save person details (height, units , and start , current and target weight) in the DB or using GetSharedPreferences(). Is it a good practice to mix 2 methods for persisting data ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are writing an android app. I suggest you store users with their related data in the database instead of using shared preferences. This way your application will be more extensible to support multiple users.

Comment: Yes, I'm developing an android app.But nowadays almost everyone have a smart phone I don't think my app need to support multiple users.         I have read  shared preferences is faster in terms of performance but question is : Is it a  good practice to use shared preferences for person details (height, units , and start , current and target weight) and database( for foods , exercise etc.) or just use DB only